# ArtifactoryPublish fails with null pointer exception

Tags: gradle, publish, artifactory

I have a java library which I want to upload to jfrog artifactory. But no matter what I do I get a null pointer exception:

`Execution failed for task :util-lib-java:artifactoryPublish.
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

It worked perfectly fine on the 3rd October this year, and failed on the 10th. We then referenced version: `classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.*"` and what I can see jfrog updated their library from 4.4.5 to 4.47 between these dates. But now when I'm trying with various versions I only get the error specified above.

My build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.2"
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


repositories
    {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local"
        }
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot-local"
        }
    }

// Android project is also using this library, so java version cannot be 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {

        // Set the base name of the artifacts
        artifactId 'util-lib-java'
        groupId group
        version version

        from components.java
    }
}
}


artifactory {
contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
publish {
    repository {
        if ( project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ) {
            repoKey =  'libs-snapshot-local'
        } else {
            repoKey =  'libs-release-local'
        }
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true
    }
    defaults {
        publications ('mavenJava')
    }
}
}
```

and the top-level build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
version = '1.0'
group = 'com.companyname'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

We're using gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip wrapper.

Stacktrace from build:

```
 * Exception is:
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':util-lib-java:artifactoryPublish'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask.prepareAndDeploy(BuildInfoBaseTask.java:346)
    at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask.collectProjectBuildInfo(BuildInfoBaseTask.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
```

What am I missing here? [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352475/upload-artifact-to-artifactory-using-gradle) don't help me

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Should be noted for folks stumbling across this issue that it should be resolved with the latest release: 4.4.10

https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/issues/101

Answer (score 0):

For publishing you have to remove this lines in you `gradle.properties` or `local.properties`:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Also you have to add this in the main `build.gradle` file.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
    ...
}
```

After that the publishing should be work.

Comment: OK, will try it out.

Comment: the suggestions for the gradle settings seem irrelevant.  Perhaps a note describing why they should be set like that would be helpful, those are two settings that greatly effect build performance.