# Uploading artifacts using Gradle to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory, artifacts

After building the Gradle project there is a **.jar** file is created in build\libs and I want to use it as Artifactory and trying to upload to libs-release-local, it looks like this

`https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/abc/xyz/blog-service/v1/`

here I can see three files blog-service-v1.jar, blog-service-v1.module, blog-service-v1.pom.

I can manually upload the .jar file and overwrite it from my local to Artifactory using

- jfrog rt u blog-service-v1.jar
- libs-release-local/com/abc/xyz/blog-service/v1/

But where would I get the other two files?

Is it created automatically in an artifact or I have to manually upload it, If I have to manually upload it then where would I get these files?

Answer (score 0):

After some changes in build.gradle ([click here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352475/upload-artifact-to-artifactory-using-gradle)) gradle uploads it to artifactory. All you need to do is run this(gradle artifactoryPublish) from your command line.